# Break into a new line after each 6th record

Tags: php, for-loop, count

I want to break to a new line after each 6th record but it only breaks after 5th record and leaving the 6th record on a own line (see picture below).

```
for($i = 1; $i < 13; $i++) {
    echo '<div style="display: '.($i % 6 == 0 ? '' : 'inline-').'block; padding: 0 10px;"></div>';
}
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? How can I fix it?

Comment: use 7 instead of 6 or start loop with $i=0

Comment: Already did. Please see my first comment for Gautam3164's answer.

Comment: can you provide a url where we canhave a look at the code? it looks like it is a css issue

Comment: An element with display:block will be 100% width (hence be on its own line) - So your whole logic is flawed.

Comment: that is exactly what I wanted to look at :)

Comment: @cornel.raiu Sure. Go to http://server-1.myftp.org/vadret-justnu/62.226996,16.040039 and click on "Framtida prognoser".

Comment: I have posted an answer. Please test that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set all the items with `display:inline-block` and after the 6th element add:

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

tested it on your website and it worked

Comment: Many thanks! Your answer did do the trick! ^^ I'll accept it as soon as I can

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `7`

```
echo '<div style="display: '.(($i % 7 == 0) ? '' : 'inline-').'block; padding: 0 10px;"></div>';
```

Comment: Already did. It shows 6 records on the first line but on the second it only shows one record and on the third line it shows 5 records

Comment: Your edit shows 8 records on the first line and 4 records on the second line

Answer (score 1):

The width of six clouds (with spacing) is probably more than the available space in the cloud container. Check for whitespaces or increase outer container width (or reduce padding)

Comment: I removed the padding from the style completely. Nothing happened besides it removed the space (of course)

Comment: Perhaps set divs to 'float:left;' and add 'clear:right;' if (n%6)==0

Comment: That didn't do the trick :/ There was no visible changes when I added `clear: right;` to the style. When I added a new DIV with `float: left` that my DIV I included in my question is in, removed the new rows completely.

Answer (score 0):

It is normal you get that result, it is rather a mathematical logic:

```
  for($i = 1; $i < 13; $i++) {
        echo '<div style="display: '.($i % 7 == 0 ? '' : 'inline-').'block; padding: 0 10px;"></div>';                                   ^
    }
```

Comment: Your answer is the exact the same as Gautam3164's answer

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, your logic is flawed as a block element will have 100% width.

Instead reduce the width of the container and leave all elements as inline-block:

```
<div id="infopage-prognosis" style="display: block; width:450px">
<?php for($i = 1; $i < 13; $i++) {
    echo '<div style="display: inline-block; padding: 0 10px;"></div>';
} ?>
</div>
```

Comment: or add <div style="clear:both"> after the 6th element :)

Comment: @cornel.raiu true, +1 to your answer